# How can I move an installed game from one Steam library folder to another?

Tags: steam

I use (and have it much bigger) drive `D:` to store all my user data and games, but I have installed the Steam client on drive `C:`. When I was installing a first game (Warhammer 40000), I've chosen to place my library folder on drive `D:` and the game went there.

But now as I've got installed the second game (Portal), I can see that it was put on drive `C:` despite to the choice I've done previously. When I open Steam - Settings - Downloads + Cloud - Steam library folders, I can see both installation places in the list. Can I merge them into one?

I would even agree to use the default drive `C:` library (as I've replaced it with a symlink already). When I press to remove one library it says it can only remove empty ones.

Comment: There is a way, using links. It's even simple, but the question is now protected by community: I can't answer

Comment: The best answer, which should be accepted, is the one by [aytimothy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/298291/194663) below. You basically right-click on the game and go to `Properties`. Then, under `Local Files` tab, you click `Move Install Folder`. That's it.

Answer (score 153):

## Before [January 19th 2017](http://store.steampowered.com/news/26953/), there was no built in method to move games between libraries

Here is what I did though:

1. Browsed to the `steamapps` folder that the game is currently installed into
2. Copied the game folder for the game I wanted to move into the other Steam library (it's important you **copy** it; don't **move** it)
3. Deleted the game within Steam (delete local content)
4. Reinstalled the game, selecting the other game library

This finished "downloading" to the new location instantly, since the files were already present in the new location.

**Important note on the folder structure of the destination library**

It is important to note that as of trying this process on 2/11/2016 you cannot simply paste the folder into the destination "steamapps" folder but instead to a "common" folder within the "steamapps" folder.

For example if you created a Steam Content Library at "D:\Games\Steam" you will want to paste your game folder into "D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common" resulting in something like "D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V"

Comment: Steam now officially supports moving games! I think this answer is no longer needed.

Comment: @HugoZink Some games do not have "Move the install folder..." option in the properties. So for them, this method is still valid.

Answer (score 50):

I took a more... technical approach.

<del>If you're not comfortable with editing files or if you just want a simpler approach, *please* use one of the other answers. Otherwise, this lets you skip having to "delete" and "reinstall" the game when you relaunch Steam — it's all seamless. It's not actually time-saving or anything, but if you want to feel badass, you can follow what I did:</del>

Note that Steam has updated the format of its `.acf` files since I originally posted this answer, such that you no longer need to edit them. It does still have the benefit of being seamless and not requiring having to "delete" and "reinstall" the game, however. I've updated my answer in the interest of not confusing future readers, but check out [sj26's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/how-can-i-move-an-installed-game-from-one-steam-library-folder-to-another/155620#155620) for a summary of basically the same updated process.

1. Find out the game's app ID in the store. (You can easily get to this by viewing the game in your library, and clicking the link that says Store Page, although this won't work for games no longer in the store such as Deadpool; you'll need to use a search function in that case.)
2. Open the `SteamApps` folder where the game resides. Make sure Steam isn't running.
3. Open the game's manifest file, `appmanifest_<app ID>.acf`, in a text editor (I did say technical).
4. Find the line that contains the string `"installdir"`. Here's mine:

   ```
   "installdir"        "Team Fortress 2"
   ```
5. This is your game folder. Typically, this folder can be found in the `common` folder within `SteamApps`; the main exception are Valve games still under the legacy distribution system and not SteamPipe, but that's out of the scope of this answer.

   If you want, back up this folder, as well as the manifest file itself.
6. Move the game's folder. In my case, I moved `Team Fortress 2` in the `common` folder from the old library to the new library.
7. Move the manifest file to the new `SteamApps` folder.
8. Relaunch Steam, and the game should be there without you having to do anything further within the program. You can just launch the game right away.

   If you want, you can verify that the game is in its new location. You can do this by right-clicking, choosing **Properties** and going to the **Local Files** tab. If your new library resides on a different drive letter, this drive letter should be reflected. From here, you can click **Browse Local Files...**. You can also **Verify Integrity of Game Cache...** but if you didn't modify any files in the process that should not be necessary.

Comment: Interesting. I love technical ways :)

Comment: The Annoying Pyro's (TAP) procedure works perfectly. No need to backup/restore. The backup and restore process takes twice as long, as you are doing TWO copies rather than one. One of my games had an "appinstalldir" of just "c:\\". I still set to the new absolute path location. TAP says if his procedure makes you squeamish to use the backup/restore, but there's no risk if you save the original ACF files. You can always just move the game back and set the ACF to its original contents.

Comment: I found this didn't work for me and Steam kept renaming it back. I then tried moving the game from `D:\...\SteamApps\common\game` to `C:\...\SteamApps\common\game` and the .acf file from `D:\...\SteamApps\appmanifest_.acf` to `C:\...\SteamApps\appmanifest_.acf`. I didn't edit the .acf file. Then I opened Steam again and it just worked. I'd post as an answer but I don't have 10 rep earned on this site.

Comment: This answer may be out of date--there doesn't appear to be an "appinstalldir" element in the acf files anymore. Instead we have "installdir" however this value is not fully-qualified; Steam appears to be interpreting it to be a relative path, although how it establishes the app's parent folder, i.e. the correct steam library, isn't clear just yet.

Comment: Just like bwerks, there dosnt seem to be an appinstalldir anymore

Comment: You can just copy the acf and common subdirectory  like pedro_sland says. I discovered this and wrote an answer before reading their comment, sorry.

Comment: There is no `appinstalldir` element in _new_ acf files. If you have games that were installed before the element was dropped, they'll still have `appinstalldir` in them. I used the powershell command `select-string -path .\*.acf -pattern appinstalldir | foreach {$_.path}` to find these legacy acf files, deleted them, then manually moved the corresponding game folders to the new library. Those games will show as not installed in Steam, but if you install them, it'll find the existing data.

Comment: @sj26: Took me long enough but thanks to JamesGecko's comment I finally understand what was happening. I've updated my answer but linked to yours as well.

Comment: That is *very* handy - moving the `acf` file along with the appropriate folder to a new Steam Folder library works perfectly. Thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 38):

Since [January 19<sup>th</sup> 2017](http://store.steampowered.com/news/26953/) it is now possible to use the built-in "Move install folder" function from within the Steam client (even without participating in the beta program).

Simply go to **[Insert Game Name] > Properties > Local Files > Move Install Folder...**, as shown below:

[image: In the big red circle.]

[That or you could move the files and the manifests over...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155620/75275)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Seriously, @Ivan mark this one as accepted answer please. It can save people tons of time and effort. I started moving folders and things like that until I scrolled down an saw this answer.

Comment: Weirdly, this button appears on all of my Steam games that I've checked, except for Half-Life 2, HL2 Episode One, and Left 4 Dead 2. Also, weird is that it appears for Half-Life 2: Deathmatch, HL2: Lost Coast and HL2: Episode Two (and I've been able to move their installation folders).

Comment: Wonder how many poor souls are still trying the 8 step processes in older answers since Steam put this feature in place?  Please make this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 36):

Steam's library folder infrastructure means you can simply exit Steam, move the acf and common subdirectory between library folders, and restart Steam.

If you want to move all your games:

1. Exit Steam.
2. Open the old and new libraries' *SteamApps* directories.

   For example, `c:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps` and `d:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps`.
3. Move all the `appmanifest_*.acf` files and the `common` directory from the old *SteamApps* directory to the new *SteamApps* directory.

   For example, `appmanifest_220.acf` is Half-Life 2's app manifest, and the `common` directory should contain the `Half-Life 2` directory.
4. Restart Steam.

If you only want to move specific games:

1. Exit Steam.
2. Find out the game's app ID in the store.

   Half-Life 2 is [on the store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/220/) at `http://store.steampowered.com/app/220/` so its app ID is `220`
3. Open the old and new libraries' *SteamApps* directories.

   For example, `c:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps` and `d:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps`.
4. Move `appmanifest_[app ID].acf` from the old *SteamApps* directory to the new *SteamApps* directory.

   For example, `appmanifest_220.acf` is Half-Life 2's app manifest.
5. Open the `appmanifest_[app ID].acf` with Notepad or your favourite text editor and look for `"installdir" "[directory name]"` where `[directory name]` is the next directory your need to move.

   For example, `"installdir" "Half-Life 2"`.
6. Open the *common* directory in both *SteamApps* directories.

   Again, `c:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common` and `d:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common`
7. Move the game directory named as above from the old *common* directory to the new *common* directory.

   Completing our example, move `c:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Half-Life 2` to `d:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Half-Life 2`.
8. Restart Steam.

Disclaimer: *Back up your library or don't care about the outcome.*

Comment: my favorite answer

Comment: This didn't work for me. Right-click -> Properties for the game in Steam still shows the old place as the installation path, and launching the game fails because Steam cannot find the executable.

Comment: This is the best answer because the folder and acf are meant to stay in sync. If the acf isn't moved, and a new acf is created with the "install" button, Steam can't know which language/dlc/etc were enabled and may download gigabytes of unwanted data.

Comment: This is the highlighted answer on [google XD](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1287098/8888771/56e00798-32c4-11e5-8c87-b76f51325030.png) , works great!

Comment: Should also add the final step of [Verify Integrity of Game Cache (steam link)](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)

Comment: How do I do this for 100 games that I moved, without sifting through 550+ games in my total installed library?

Answer (score 10):

I done something similar few months ago.

As far as I remember I simply turn off Steam then cut and paste game folders from my HDD `steamapps` to external Drive `steamapps` folder. After turning on Steam "repaired" games downloading 100-200 MB and that was it.

Here you [have tutorial from Valve](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129) how to do similar stuff.

Comment: While I have not had my steam folder separated like the OP, I have moved the full steam folder several times and across computers (upgrades) by turning off steam and moving the folder. Steam figured this out right away and recovered pretty easily as you stated.

Comment: This works for moving the SteamApps directory wholesale, but unfortunately not consistently for individual games.  One must follow kalina's directions to solve OP's (and my) issue.

Answer (score 8):

I have created a video on how to do something like this.

Basically, you backup the games to a location, then delete the games' local content, then go to **Steam > Backup and Restore Games**

Restore your games and pick the new location for them to install to. All from disc; no downloading.

Comment: Most awful experience ever. tl;dr: Don't do it.. It won't only NOT always succeed, it will last forever..

Comment: @bora I haven't had trouble with steam backups, although occasionally restoring from them ends up with you downloading a lot of data anyway because of updates. I find it best to do backup one game at a time, rather than backing up the whole shebang.