# Is it possible to make steam detect that I've copy-pasted the dlc into the game folder?

Tags: steam, dota-2

I'm trying to install the DoTA 2 reborn beta by flashdrive from another computer with the beta installed. I copied the "steamapps/common/dota 2 beta" folder, but the DLC did not get detected. How can I have steam detect the DLC?

Comment: Have you checked the DLC for Steam to download? Once it begins downloading, stop it and verify integrity, if it didn't do it automatically.

Comment: Related [questions here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12695/61395) [and here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96370/61395). Those are about moving games but dlc and games are similar for Steam.

Answer (score 2):

In your steam library, right-click on Dota2 and select `Backup and ..`. It will ask the location to save the backup and take sometime to finish the backup process. Then copy that to a harddrive (or USB stick) if the destination PC is a different one. Go to the steam library on that machine, right-click and select `.. restore` and it will copy the files over for you. This should work for the actual game and the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy over its acf file too. For dota 2 it's "appmanifest_570.acf" located in the steamapps folder.